# Display JavaFX "border" selection over -fx-background-color?

Tags: java, css, tableview, javafx-8, styling

[image: My Problem]

I have styled all cells that match "Liste" like that:

```
.table-cell-in-main
{
    -fx-background-color: thistle;
}
.table-row-cell:selected .table-cell-in-main
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

The "normal" selection works and goes blue as is should - but the "border" selection (achieved by selecting one row and then navigating with Ctrl + Arrowkeys) doesn't show on the styled field, that looks really bad. What do I have to change to make it look like this?

[image: How it should look like]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, in that it relies on the current Modena styles, but you can add insets to your cell background to “make room" for the TableRow selection border:

```
.table-cell-in-main {
    -fx-background-color: thistle;
    -fx-background-insets: 2 0 2 0;
}
```

Comment: Well it's something I guess